# What is the default typography of a UINavigationBar text label in ios 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, typography

I am creating a UILabel in a custom view and want it to match the typography (font and size) of the default UINavigationBar labels.

Like so:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 44.0) ];
titleLabel.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
titleLabel.center = CGPointMake([self screenWidth] / 2.0, 42.0);
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:(18.0)];
titleLabel.text = @"Forgot Password";
```

Does anyone know the font and point size?

Comment: Helvetica-Neue is the default font used in iOS 7

Comment: it is Helvetica-Neue Medium (a little bold) for title

Comment: Oh thanks. So for other text in the nav bar, like a text button on the left, its Helvetica-NeueLight correct?